# Sorting, and creating columns in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm a student doing a project and I have to use SQLite however i'm new to SQLite. I have described my problem below.

I have a table(containing 60000 rows) which is of the form shown below.

```
Date_Time           Country_City Temperature
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_NYC        20
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_LA         17
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_DC         19
4-10-2012 12:40:10  USA_LA         18
4-10-2012 12:40:10  USA_DC         18
```

I have to sort and create the table as shown below, if the data is missing as in NYC the data must be 'NaN'. If all the rows contain 'NaN' for a single time stamp it must be eliminated.

```
Date_Time         USA_NYC USA_LA USA_DC
4-10-2012 12:10:10 20      17     19
4-10-2012 12:40:10 NaN     18     18
```

Can you please tell me how to create it, I could order and sort, but I do not know how to create like this in SQLite. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is certainly not SQLite-specific but rather addresses the formulation of the right SQL query. Having had a quick look at what you want to achieve I am certain it is possible in plain SQL-92.

Currently I am not sure if I would answer a homework assignment if I'd post the solution. As thus I'll just give hints: Have a look at sub-queries (select Date_Time, USA_NYC from ...) in combination with joins/outer joins.

Regarding the NaN values, I'm not sure if you'd want that or rather have NULL values. If you really need a string value of 'NaN' then you can use a case construct to convert NULL values into the 'NaN' string.

Where I see difficulties: If you don't know what columns (e.g., USA_NYC) to expect in advance, it can get trickier (tell us if this is the case).

Answer (score 0):

First, these queries get all possible timestamp and city values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time FROM mytable
SELECT DISTINCT Country_City FROM mytable
```

By cross-joining the results, we get all possible combination (even those that do not exist in the table). We can then look up those temperature values that exist with an outer join:

```
SELECT t1.Date_Time,
       t1.Country_City,
       Temperature
FROM ((SELECT DISTINCT Date_Time    FROM mytable)
      JOIN
      (SELECT DISTINCT Country_City FROM mytable)) t1
     LEFT JOIN mytable t2
     ON t1.Date_Time = t2.Date_Time AND t1.Country_City = t2.Country_City
```

The result looks like this:

```
t1.Date_Time        t1.Country_City  Temperature
------------------  ---------------  -----------
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_NYC          20
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_LA           17
4-10-2012 12:10:10  USA_DC           19
4-10-2012 12:40:10  USA_NYC                   <-- NULL
4-10-2012 12:40:10  USA_LA           18
4-10-2012 12:40:10  USA_DC           18
```

Getting the cities as columns automatically is not possible without pivot functions, which SQLite does not have.